# How to transition from a triangle to a circle

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, polygon

I have some images masked with clip-paths in CSS to show equilateral triangles. I want them to expand and become circles on hover.

Here's my CSS:

```
.tri-Up {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    transition: 2s;
}
a:hover .tri-Up,
a:focus .tri-Up {
  -webkit-clip-path:circle(50%,50%,75%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,75%);
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <img src="img/photo.png" class="tri-Up img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

And a jsfiddle, where the transition isn't working:
http://jsfiddle.net/kjaog69j/

I've found a bit of stuff online, but nothing going from triangle to circle, much less expanding. I've extensively googled and been through "animating CSS shapes, W3Schools on CSS transitions, CSStricks, and the like. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this helps you. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azyVqx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach trying to push it to the limit. This is of course experimental code, since it is just supported in Chrome, as far as I know, and somehow in a buggy way.

clip path can not be animated if you don't make it easy for the browser. That is, the paths must be somehow *equivalents*. One way to achieve this in you case would be to transform a circle to a very wide ellipse. And defining the circle as an ellipse, where both radii are equal.

But this can give us only one side of the triangle, so we will need 3 nested elements, each rotated 120 deg, to get the triangle

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.container {
  width: 540px;
  height: 540px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.test1 {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1600px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  top: -544px;
  left: -544px;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 1000px 196px at 800px 735px);
  z-index: 10;
}

.container:hover .test1 {
   -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 256px 256px at 800px 800px); 
}


.test2 {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 1000px 196px at 550px 485px);
}

.container:hover .test2, .test2:hover {
   -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 256px 256px at 550px 550px); 
}

.test3 {
  /* display: none; */
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  top: 175px;
  left: 175px;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 1000px 196px at 375px 310px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/628/800);
}

.container:hover .test3, .test3:hover {
   -webkit-clip-path: ellipse( 256px 256px at 375px 375px); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="test1">
<div class="test2">
<div class="test3">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
a:hover .tri-Up,
a:focus .tri-Up {
  -webkit-clip-path:circle(50%,50%,75%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,75%);
}
```

to this

```
a:hover .tri-Up,
a:focus .tri-Up {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 50px 50px);
  clip-path: circle(50px at 50px 50px);
}
```

here is a demo

```css
.tri-Up {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  transition: 2s;
}

a:hover .tri-Up,
a:focus .tri-Up {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 50px 50px);
  clip-path: circle(50px at 50px 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/560x484" class="tri-Up img-responsive" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Tambo, thanks so much for responding. This does work to an extent, so it's much appreciated. But the transition still isn't working (i.e it snaps from shape to shape). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change clip-path for circle.

Modified CSS:

```
.tri-Up {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    transition: 2s;
}


a:hover .tri-Up,
a:focus .tri-Up {

-webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 50px 50px);
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjaog69j/1/

Although would advise to not use clip-path but use simple height, width and border-radius for defining polygon/shapes.

Comment: This works, but for some reason the transition effect doesn't happen. i.e it snaps from circle to triangle instead of transitioning. Any thoughts on that? Also, I've been desperately trying to use height, width, and border-radius instead of clip path, because my clipping code doesn't work on firefox (cardinal sin of website creation, I know). I have tried svg, javascript, everything. If you have ANY idea on how to edit the class to make these equilateral triangles with something that will work cross-browser, I'd be hugely grateful

Comment: Yes. That would happen. That is the reason I suggested to use normal methods instead of clip path. For some reason clippath hinders transition. But if you use simple methods like height, width and border radius then it would transition as expected.

Comment: I attempted to use those with no success. Do you have any idea or css code on how to make an equilateral triangle using height width and border radius?

Comment: Yes. It is easy. Just don't give border attribute in css to that where you want it to be pointed. Check this out.
<div class = "triangle"> </div>

.triangle {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 30px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 30px solid #f00;
}

Comment: Yea, that works, but the issue is that then it's not responsive. I appreciate the help though!